# ViewControllers as instance variables

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, instance-variables

I have a custom ViewController which is an instance variable of my root viewController.

I intend to modally present it whenever a button is touch. Therefore the viewController will be presented and dismissed potentially many many times.

I obviously only want to alloc init my instance variable once as the modal viewController is not deallocated each time it's dismissed, so should I have code like this inside my button action to ensure that it's only alloc and inited once?:

```
if(!myViewController)
{
    ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];  
}
[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: I think you meant that the modal view controller *is* deallocated, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use lazy instatiation in those cases:

Declare a property for your ViewController:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *myViewController;
```

After that you can override the get of `myViewController`

```
-(UIViewController*) myViewController {
    if(!_myViewController) {
        _myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    }

    return _myViewController;
}
```

This way you guarantee that was only instantiated once and is always there when you needed.

**ATTENTION**

This works well if you always use `self.myViewController`. I consider a good practice that properties' generated iVars should **only** be accessed in their setters/getters.

Comment: Then you need to use "self.myViewController" to use the getter!

Comment: Thought that was obvious, but you are right. I have just added that note. Thanks for that @Geraud.ch

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Thanks, So in the rootView controller I have no If statement, I just always alloc init right? Then the init method of the modal view controller determines if itself is already created?

Comment: @JohnWoods in the `rootViewController` you simply use your `myViewController` calling `self.myViewController`. What is going to happen is: You call `self.myViewController` when you need it and that get (`-(UIViewController*) myViewController`) is going to be called. Then it checks "did myViewController was created yet?" and if it wasn't it will alloc init, otherwise it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to ensure that only one instance of the view controller active at a time.

```
if(myViewController) {
  [myViewController release];
   myViewController = nil;
}

myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];  

[self presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

You need to make `myViewController` as class variable.

Comment: Why does it have to be a class variable? Would an instance variable (aka an ivar) not be a better fit with your code?

Comment: The idea is more to keep one instance of the VC which is good for performance reason. In your case, you remove the "old" VC and create a new one. Be careful this code is not arc compliant.

Comment: We have to make the myViewController a class variable so that we can release the object before allocating memory. So that we have only one instance active at a time.  Geraud.ch is right .this is a non ARC code. I was suggesting a method so that only one instance is active at a time